# php codesniffer returns nothing ... is my code in standard?

Tags: php, pear, code-standards, phpcodesniffer, psr-1

I have a laravel application (created with composer) that I am trying to ensure meets PHP coding standards (level PSR-1). I run:

```
$ phpcs --standard=PSR1 my_app/
```

And within a few seconds it returns with just a new, empty, ready-to-go command line:

```
$
```

Does this mean my code meets all requirements and standards in PSR-1? It does the same with just:

```
$ phpcs my_app/
$ phpcs --standard=PEAR my_app/
$ phpcs --standard=PSR1 --report=summary lauras_app/
```

I just want to make sure that if the commands return nothing, that means my code is in standard. Thank you!

Comment: Make a line with invalid code and see if it catches it.

Answer (score 2):

Phpcs does not output anything if it does detect no errors.
From their [doc](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Usage):

> By default, PHP_CodeSniffer will run quietly, only printing the report
>   of errors and warnings at the end. If you are checking a large number
>   of files, you may have to wait a while to see the report. If you want
>   to know what is happening, you can turn on progress or verbose output.

There are 2 different options to see what `phpcs` is doing.

Using `show_progress`

> With progress output enabled, PHP_CodeSniffer will print a
>   single-character status for each file being checked

```
phpcs --config-set show_progress 1 --standard=PSR1 my_app/
```

or `-p`.

```
phpcs -p --standard=PSR1 my_app/
```

The second option is to use the verbose flag `-v`. You can set it up to `-vvv` to increase the details.

> With verbose output enabled, PHP_CodeSniffer will print the file that
>   it is checking, show you how many tokens and lines the file contains,
>   and let you know how long it took to process.

```
phpcs -v --standard=PSR1 my_app/
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the file extension: you have to specify the file extension if it is not a standard one:

> By default, PHP_CodeSniffer will check any file it finds with a .inc,
>   .php, .js or .css extension,

[WIKI](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#specifying-valid-file-extensions)

To check a .module file:

```
phpcs --standard=Drupal --extensions=module example.module
```